# i have write a class which always delegate it's function parameter to on of it's member, how can i improve the code

Tags: c++, design-patterns

how can i refactor this code, this kind of code structure really smells bad.

example code below:

```
class A {
public:
    void init(){
        // do something and init b
    }
    auto foo(auto p, auto q){
        return b.foo(p, q); 
    }
    auto bar(auto p, auto q){
        // maybe do something here
        return b.bar(p, q); 
    }
    // all kinds of funcs like foo and bar
private:
    B b;
}
```

is there any design pattern or best practice for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because design improvements in working code are more appropriate for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: what are you doing is called PIMPL

Comment: i don't think it's the same with pimpl, cause the two class, A and B, have there own logic. but it do smell bad when most funcs of B is called by A by direct delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance:

```
class A : public B
public:
    void init(){
        // do something and init b
    }
}
```

Now all public methods of B are public on A as well.

Comment: This isn't the same thing. It's not delegating to one of its members.

Comment: in reality, A is a thread class that manages B, but when other thread need something about B, i have to delegate function call through A. i don't think inheritace is an accurate relationship for them.

Comment: @laughing: then it looks like you want AOP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming